# Is there a way to loop through a list, and assign a variable

Tags: python, list, append, typeerror

What I'd like to do is assign variable (a) to each instance of (b). There are 30 folders within (a) It should look like the following:
'm:/groupfolder/susan/01'
'm:/groupfolder/susan/03'
'm:/groupfolder/susan/04'
...

Here is what I'm doing -

```
import os
from os import listdir
a = ('m:/groupfolder/susan')
b = []
for x in os.listdir(a):
   b.append(x)

fha = [b]
for y in fha:
    path = a+b
 Error mesage = "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str"
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong - yes I'm relatively new to Python and still learning.
Thanks

Comment: fha is a list of list. Not a list of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of collecting all filename in list and then iterating it again. You can simply do it in one step :

```py
import os                                                                                                                                                              

b = []                                                                                                                                                                 
for file in os.listdir(s): 
    print(file) 
    b.append(s+'/'+file) 

print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to get a list of full file paths:

```
import os
file_paths = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir('dir_name')]
print(file_paths)
```